# SBS 2011 Premium Add-on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-sbs-2011

We have set up a new Intel server running Windows HyperV Server R2.

Two VMs are running:

- Microsoft SBS 2011
- Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (Installed from the SBS 2011 Premium Add-on disc)

The package we bought has the Premium add-on with the Windows Server and the SQL server.

I've got both VMs installed and running, the 2008 R2 Premium Addon box has joined the domain controlled by the SBS 2011 VM.  When I run the SQL Server installer I get an error on its prerequisite checks:

> Rule "Operating system supported for edition" failed
>
> This SQL Server edition is not supported on this operating system
>   See SQL Server Books Online for information about supported
>   operating systems for SQL Small Business Server edition.

As I understand it - the SQL Server is supposed to run on the add-on server, not on the DC.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check if you are installing SQL Server on a server in the same domain of the SBS.  Even if you think it was, it may have lost trust - so try rejoining the computer to the same domain.